# Visual Studio Resharper Tab Panel

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I use visual studio 2015, Resharper and PowerTools.

I use powertools to give me sidebar for tabs, but ReSharper's Known Compatibility Problems reports Powertools. It can make ReSharper slower.

Do you now some plugin to put tabs, left or right?
I'm trying use something free.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just running the Productivity Power Tools as well as ReSharper. This is how I run it, and it all works fine. You can always disable some of the functionality, if you're concerned about performance (e.g. I disable align assignments, column guides, ctrl+click go to definition, amongst others. Not necessarily because they cause perf issues, but because I don't want them).

Basically, give it a go. If you think it's slowing things down, use dotTrace to profile and confirm that there's a conflict.